# Node Error spawn /bin/sh ENOENT on remote server

Tags: python, node.js

Okay I know there are multiple questions regarding this topic, I read most of them and nothing helped.

I am trying to have a node server run a python script periodically. For this I've got the following code:

```
const
    { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');


let config = [
{
    "title": "My Python Script",
    "description": "A script that can scrape website data",
    "command": "python3 collect_data.py",
    "dir": "../file_folder",
    "minutesBetweenExecution": 60
}
];



const intervals = [];


function startCronjobs() {
    while (intervals.length > 0) {
        clearInterval(intervals.pop());
    }

    console.log("Starting cronjobs...")

    for (let i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
        const cron = config[i];
        const func = () => {
            exec(cron.command, { cwd: cron.dir, timeout: 40 * 60000 }, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (err) {
                    // node couldn't execute the command
                    console.error('Command could not be executed. Error: ', err, ' cron entry: ', cron.title);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Output after ', cron.title);
                // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            });
        };

        intervals.push(setInterval(func, parseInt(cron.minutesBetweenExecution) * 60000));
        console.log('Started Cronjob', cron.title);
        func();
    }
}

startCronjobs();
```

As you can see, the script just runs exec with a specified command and working directory.
Yet, when trying to execute `func()` node throws the error specified above.

Stuff I've tried to fix this:

- Use an absolute path for the working directory
- checked if `python3` is in PATH: `which python3` returns `/usr/bin/python3`
- run the node server with `sudo`
- debug logged `process.env.PATH`: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

The weird thing about this is: When I am trying to run this on my local linux machine, it works perfectly. On my remote server, however, it does not. What am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is that remote server? `/bin/sh` is missing, so it's not a regular Linux server I'd say.

Comment: it is a regular cloud server running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: So you can log in on that server and execute `/bin/sh` yourself? You _could_ try to use the `shell` option for `child_process.exec` so it points directly to the Python executable, but it seems strange that a regular Linux server doesn't have `/bin/sh`

Comment: `/bin/sh -c ls` shows the folder contents, so yeah, it does exist

Comment: Ruling out an invalid shell, the only other reason I can think of that will cause that error is an invalid `cwd`, but you already ruled that out too. So still strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, I am an idiot.

The folder on my local machine is named differently from the git repo and therefore the folder on the server, because I just git cloned it.

Fix: change `_` in the working directory to `-` and it works...